# Offsetting polygon borders where they share border in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, borders

Say you have 2 polygons with different coloured borders, where the borders are shared the colour is problematic.

How do you offset/separate them in QGIS 2.10.1?

Comment: [Your question title should be a summary of what is in your question body.](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115). Please always mention the software and version that you are using in the question body.  There is a 2-minute [Tour] that introduces users to the site and its protocols which you appear not to have taken.

Comment: Maybe this site could be of help: [Drawing polygon borders only inside the polygon](http://nyalldawson.net/2014/01/qgis-two-neat-features-in-2-2/).